# Would this suffice in a visual type theory to define an abstract List type?

Tags: math-software, visualization, type-theory, data-structure

See the image.  I got that from: [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_(abstract_data_type)#Abstract_definition).  In that, I don't understand the first function `nil : () -> L`.  What is `()`?

I want to make a visual type theory so that we aren't stuck comprehending pure text for eternity.

Also, is the abstract type `List` a product of some sort? The diagram doesn't indicate this since it's based on a product diagram of $E \times L$.

[image: Definition of list using product]

Assume that product has already been defined by a similar diagram and that there is a system that can interpret these smallish diagrams, so that ideally $E\times L$ and $p_L$ as well as the graphical arrows and blocks show up in a different color indicating that you cannot edit them.

Additionally in the wikipedia article, they say:

```
for any element e and any list l. It is implicit that

cons (e, l) ≠ l
cons (e, l) ≠ e
cons (e1, l1) = cons (e2, l2) if e1 = e2 and l1 = l2
Note that first (nil ()) and rest (nil ()) are not defined.
```

But isn't the last one already true!??  How should I indicate the first two in diagram form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Q: I don't understand the first function nil: () → L. What is ()?

It is an atom, written as an abstract data type. The [List is created and initialized as empty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_(abstract_data_type)), using the atom. In [Lisp](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lisp_(programming_language)): Set an [atom](http://shrager.org/llisp/4.html) to NIL and initialize the [list](http://shrager.org/llisp/2.html) with that atom.

`nil: () → L`

That creates an [empty list](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lisp_(programming_language)#Lists). It's like: `char *L = (char *)malloc(0);`

See: [What's the point in malloc(0)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2022335/whats-the-point-in-malloc0).

> Q: Also, is the abstract type List a product of some sort?

It's a list, see link above for "list".

> Q: But isn't the last one already true!??

It says:

> for any element e and any list l. It is implicit that

```
cons (e, l) ≠ l
cons (e, l) ≠ e
cons (e1, l1) = cons (e2, l2) if e1 = e2 and l1 = l2
```

It's [implicit](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/implicit).

> Q:  How should I indicate the first two in diagram form?
>
> [CONS](http://shrager.org/llisp/3.html) takes its first argument [which may be either an atom or a list] and inserts it just after the first left parenthesis in the second argument. This second argument should be a list. CONS will actually connect things onto atoms as: "(cons 'a 'b)", but this creates a special form of list called a dotted pair.

Comment: how is the first one implied?

Comment: It is "any element e and any list l" that is implicit to the following conditions, which are explained. The "first one" isn't implicit, it's stated clearly that it's !=l .

Comment: I don't see where it's stated....